# Can 6/2 return a different result than 6/a (where a=2)? (and how that affects the output of a .bmp file)

Tags: c, bmp, cs50, fseek

I am working on an assignment in which a program to resize `.bmp` images has to be written.

I know the title might sound weird but I find myself with this situation.

I have this piece of code:

```
if (l < factor - 1)
        {
            fseek(inptr, -(bi.biWidth / factor), SEEK_CUR);
        }
```

Now, I would like you to focus on the *offset*. `bi.biWidth == 6` and `factor == 2`, so `-(bi.biWidth / factor)` should equal -3. 
With the code written above, the output is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kS62.jpg).

And, writing directly -3, like this:

```
if (l < factor - 1)
        {
            fseek(inptr, -3, SEEK_CUR);
        }
```

the output is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4oob.jpg).

So, apparently it should return the same, but it doesn't. And I would like to know why.

P.S.: In case it matters, `factor` is a command line argument that's been through `atoi`, and `bi.biWidth` is called from another file (and has also been multiplied with the `factor`variable above, before being written in the code I attached - still I don't think that matters).

**EDIT1**: `LONG` is an `int32_t` type. `factor` is an `int` type.

**EDIT2**: full code: https://pastebin.com/TYjQkupw and headers definitions: https://pastebin.com/aAY3U2fG

**LAST EDIT**: I will close this question soon. Among others, the main problem was that the IDE, for some reason that the course's staff is still trying to figure out, wasn't showing the actual pixels of the .bmp files. As a file, the output was perfect, but on the screen it didn't look like that. The Staff checked my outputs in their computers and all them saw perfect/normal .bmp files; they couldn't understand my problem until I sent them an imgur link showing what I was seeing on my screen -which was completely different from what they saw in theirs, even though the .bmp files were the same.
*Thanks to everyone that took some time to answer my question!*

Comment: Are you doing float or integer division?

Comment: The entire question boils down to what `bi.biWidth` and `factor` are (their types and values), yet this is omitted. Please include an MCVE. Have you tried assigning the result of the division in an intermediate variable and looking at it with a debugger?

Comment: @SLaks Thanks for writing so quickly. `factor` is an `int` and `bi.biWidth` was a `LONG` at the very beginning, but then was multiplied by `factor` (which is an `int`). I would say that that makes `bi.biWidth` still a `LONG`... but I'm not sure. Thanks again!

Comment: @GManNickG Thanks as well! I will try what you say and come back to you with a shorter example of just the division!

Comment: If you provide all of the relevant code, then people can debug it faster.  We want to see how variables are defined at the minimum.

Comment: What's a `LONG`?  It isn't a standard C type — in the sense that it is not mentioned in the ISO standard for C.  It may be commonly used on some platform (possibly Microsoft Windows), but …  If either `bi.biWidth` or `factor` is an unsigned type, then the negation of a small unsigned value is a rather large (unsigned and hence positive) number.

Comment: Still working on an MCVE, @GManNickG; but regarding new comments: this school assignment had two versions: the difficult one involved `floats`, the easy one (THIS ONE) only `ints`, so I would say: there is no `float`.
**More importantly**: as far as I can tell `LONG` is an `int32_t` and `factor` is just an `int`.
Also, regarding some new suggestions of **posting the full code**, here it is: [https://pastebin.com/TYjQkupw](https://pastebin.com/TYjQkupw) and the definitions from the header: [https://pastebin.com/aAY3U2fG](https://pastebin.com/aAY3U2fG).
Thank you all again!!

Comment: Well, everything (including the fseek parameter) is an int, and signed at that, so you should indeed get -3 as a result of that expression. See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb00a4f4d71c0c2d How did you verify that those variables did in fact have the values you say they do?

Comment: @GManNickG Sorry for the delay, but it took me a while doing the MCVE: https://pastebin.com/zbRuZcrb First one I ever do, so I hope it's concise enough, there's really nothing more I can delete. I have tried what you suggested in your comment (intermediate variable and debugger), and it didn't work either. Thank you, again, very much!!

Comment: hi and thanks again @GManNickG. I have `printf`'s to verify a series of variables, including the result of the division. (I deleted them in the MCVE, but in my terminal they were printing the values I expected). The only "mistery" is the .bmp output file.

Comment: Change `fopen(infile, "r");` --> `fopen(infile, "rb");`,

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @chux; it didn't work though.

Comment: LAST EDIT: I will close this question soon. Among others, the main problem was that the IDE, for some reason that the course's staff is still trying to figure out, wasn't showing the actual pixels of the .bmp files. As a file, the output was perfect, but on the screen it didn't look like that. The Staff checked my outputs in their computers and all them saw perfect/normal .bmp files; they couldn't understand my problem until I sent them an imgur link showing what I was seeing on my screen -which was completely different from what they saw in theirs, even though the .bmp files were the same.TY!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks to everyone who helped and tried to solve this question.

**This is the answer** to it (also added as a "last edit" in the question text): apparently, the problem had nothing to do with the code. There was some kind of problem in my IDE/screen/computer (still not clear), that made the output look different than it actually was.

*To make it cristal clear, it was like if my computer performed a sum (1+2) and, in the inside, the processors knew the result was 3, but still -for some unknowkn reason- the screen showed a 4.*

So that's what happened. The course staff still does not know why, but the code was "okay".

Thanks again!!